# Hibernate order by with nulls last

Tags: java, hibernate, null, sql-order-by

Hibernate used with PostgreSQL DB while ordering desc by a column puts null values higher than not null ones.

SQL99 standard offers keyword "NULLS LAST" to declare that null values should be put lower than not nulls.

Can "NULLS LAST" behaviour be achieved using Hibernate's Criteria API?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Given that [HHH-465](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-465) is not fixed and is not going to get fixed in a near future for the reasons given by Steve Ebersole, your best option would be to use the `CustomNullsFirstInterceptor` attached to the issue either globally or specifically to alter the SQL statement.

I'm posting it below for the readers (credits to Emilio Dolce):

```
public class CustomNullsFirstInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3156853534261313031L;

    private static final String ORDER_BY_TOKEN = "order by";

    public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {

        int orderByStart = sql.toLowerCase().indexOf(ORDER_BY_TOKEN);
        if (orderByStart == -1) {
            return super.onPrepareStatement(sql);
        }
        orderByStart += ORDER_BY_TOKEN.length() + 1;
        int orderByEnd = sql.indexOf(")", orderByStart);
        if (orderByEnd == -1) {
            orderByEnd = sql.indexOf(" UNION ", orderByStart);
            if (orderByEnd == -1) {
                orderByEnd = sql.length();
            }
        }
        String orderByContent = sql.substring(orderByStart, orderByEnd);
        String[] orderByNames = orderByContent.split("\\,");
        for (int i=0; i<orderByNames.length; i++) {
            if (orderByNames[i].trim().length() > 0) {
                if (orderByNames[i].trim().toLowerCase().endsWith("desc")) {
                    orderByNames[i] += " NULLS LAST";
                } else {
                    orderByNames[i] += " NULLS FIRST";
                }
            }
        }
        orderByContent = StringUtils.join(orderByNames, ",");
        sql = sql.substring(0, orderByStart) + orderByContent + sql.substring(orderByEnd); 
        return super.onPrepareStatement(sql);
    }

}
```

Comment: Pretty solution, I haven't thought about interceptors, thanks! In case somebody else wants to use this, you need to add this line to your persistence.xml file: <property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor" value="com.example.CustomNullsFirstInterceptor"/>

Comment: This breaks if sql has limit/offset after order by

Comment: Wow, that Hibernate JIRA was opened in **2005**

Comment: it appears HHH-465 was fixed with version 4.2 (Mar. 2013)

Answer (score 62):

This feature has been implemented during Hibernate 4.2.x and 4.3.x releases as previously mentioned.

It can be used as for example:

```
Criteria criteria = ...;
criteria.addOrder( Order.desc( "name" ).nulls(NullPrecedence.FIRST) );
```

Hibernate v4.3 javadocs are less omissive [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Order.html#nulls%28org.hibernate.NullPrecedence%29).

Comment: So glad I scrolled down. This is happening more often every time. Best answer is not the accepted answer.

Answer (score 13):

You can configure "nulls first" / "nulls last" in hibernate properties so it will be picked up by any criteria call by default: `hibernate.order_by.default_null_ordering=last` (or `=first`).

See [this hibernate commit](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/commit/add6aea6c64bf375a5b2bad7655c5914f1a48b48) for details.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, in our case, was cleaner than other solutions; the system will behave in the same way all the time without making code changes.

Comment: This is really handy since there is on option to set `NullPrecedence` using JPA Criteria API yet

Comment: Thanks for the solution. In case If someone wants to achieve via spring boot + spring-data-jpa you can use the below config in application.properties
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_by.default_null_ordering=last

Answer (score 4):

We can create **Pageable** object with following **Sort** parameter:

```
JpaSort.unsafe(Sort.Direction.ASC, "ISNULL(column_name), (column_name)")
```

We can prepare HQL as well:

```
String hql = "FROM EntityName e ORDER BY e.columnName NULLS LAST";
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my update to the class by (Pascal Thivent):

```
for (int i = 0; i < orderByNames.length; i++) {
    if (orderByNames[i].trim().length() > 0) {
        String orderName = orderByNames[i].trim().toLowerCase();
        if (orderName.contains("desc")) {
            orderByNames[i] = orderName.replace("desc", "desc NULLS LAST");
        } else {
            orderByNames[i] = orderName.replace("asc", "asc NULLS FIRST");
        }
    }
}
```

This fixes the problem:

> This breaks if sql has limit/offset after order by – Sathish Apr 1 '11 at 14:52

Also here's how you can use this within JPA (hibernate):

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
Session nullsSortingProperlySession = null;
try {
    // perform a query guaranteeing that nulls will sort last
    nullsSortingProperlySession = session.getSessionFactory().withOptions()
        .interceptor(new GuaranteeNullsFirstInterceptor())
        .openSession();
} finally {
    // release the session, or the db connections will spiral
    try {
        if (nullsSortingProperlySession != null) {
            nullsSortingProperlySession.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error closing session", e);
    }
}
```

I've tested this on postgres and it fixes the 'nulls are higher than non-nulls' issue that we were having.

Answer (score 2):

Another variant, if you create SQL on the fly and don't use Criteria API:

ORDER BY COALESCE(,'0') [ASC|DESC]

This works either for varchar or numeric columns.

Comment: Are you sure, COALESCE is supported by Hibernate? Eben in native SQL, I am not sure that all DMS support it?

Comment: I've tested it with PostgreSQL and Oracle. And, coalesce is a part of Ansi SQL-92 standard, so it should be supported by all vendors.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the notice from 6 yrs later but I get NULL FIRST with this, is there any other option to get null last?

Answer (score 1):

For future travellers... I solved this by overriding the Hibernate dialect. I needed to add null first for asc and null last for desc by default in CriteriaQuery, which is for some reason not supported. (It's supported in legacy CriteriaAPI)

```
package io.tolgee.dialects.postgres

import org.hibernate.NullPrecedence
import org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect

@Suppress("unused")
class CustomPostgreSQLDialect : PostgreSQL10Dialect() {

  override fun renderOrderByElement(expression: String?, collation: String?, order: String?, nulls: NullPrecedence?): String {
    if (nulls == NullPrecedence.NONE) {
      if (order == "asc") {
        return super.renderOrderByElement(expression, collation, order, NullPrecedence.FIRST)
      }
      if (order == "desc") {
        return super.renderOrderByElement(expression, collation, order, NullPrecedence.LAST)
      }
    }
    return super.renderOrderByElement(expression, collation, order, nulls)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[There appears to be a change request/bug ticket open for this](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-465)

Comment: I've downloaded the lastest Hibernate version and have not observed any change in behaviour. Have you? Besides that, the formal status of the ticket is still opened and unresolved.