# Java: Hibernate Criteria API order by nulls last

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm using Hibernate Criteria API to get my search results on Employee table. I'm creating left joins to the search fields that are related to the Employee.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Employee.class).setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

criteria.createAlias("locations", "loc", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
criteria.createAlias("designations", "desig", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
criteria.createAlias("project", "ps", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);

Junction disjunction = Restrictions.disjunction();
disjunction.add(Restrictions.like("loc.locationName", "%" + loc + "%"));
disjunction.add(Restrictions.like("desig.designation", "%" + fa + "%"));
disjunction.add(Restrictions.like("ps.project", "%" + fa + "%"));

criteria.add(disjunction);
```

From the above code I do get the list but some of the employees might have 2 fields null. I want to the the employee with most not null fields on top. Is this the right approach?

I saw this question about NULLS LAST in hibernate: [Hibernate order by with nulls last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683174/hibernate-order-by-with-nulls-last)
This question talks about the [HHH-465](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-465) bug that wasn't fixed when this question was asked. But now they have fixed it. I couldn't find any implementation code for this though. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.