# JpaSort using 'nulls last' with Spring Data

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

How do I use JpaSort in Spring Data to return nulls last?

I currently use this kind of construct for my sorting:

```
new JpaSort( JpaSort.path( Datasheet_.componentSubtype )
                    .dot( ComponentSubtype_.componentType )
                    .dot( ComponentType_.name ) )
                    .and( new JpaSort( JpaSort.path( Datasheet_.componentSubtype )
                                              .dot( ComponentSubtype_.name ) ) )
```

I saw [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22671795/40064) that the Hibernate critaria API does allow it, but would like to use JPA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: you can't, as JPA (read: neither Criteria API nor JPQL) doesn't define means to define the sort ordering for `null`s.

You might wanna look into using [Querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/) as an alternative as our [matching abstraction](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/querydsl/QSort.html) exposes the necessary API to define this. Note however, Querydsl uses persistence provider specific extensions to the JPQL generated

Comment: I am using MySQL for this specific project, I suppose that will be supported?

Comment: I haven't tried but the important step is not the database but whether the persistence provider (Hibernate, EclipseLink, etc.) supports the query expressions in general. I assume, Querydsl assumes, they do, that's why the implement the functionality.

Comment: Trying to implement this now, but got stuck. Asked a separate question for it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502137/querydsl-sorting-not-working-with-spring-data

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Spring Data Pageable in Spring MVC controller in this way

`@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public Page<Address> list(Pageable pageable) {...}`

And you are using MySql, these URL params might help

```
?page=0&size=100&sort=isnull(streetLine2)&sort=streetLine2,desc
```

Comment: A pause for applause. Thank you!

Comment: I tried this and I got org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException saying 'No property isnull(name) found for type XYZ'. Seems like it is looking for isnull(name) in XYZ instead of checking if name is null. Any clue ? Thanks! Spring data jpa version is 1.11.7 and DB is mysql.