# QueryDSL sorting not working with Spring Data

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I am currently using `JpaSort` with Spring Data commons 1.9.1 and Spring JPA 1.7.1. I need to use QueryDSL because [JPA does not allow defining the sort for null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897376/jpasort-using-nulls-last-with-spring-data).

This is my Repository

```
public interface DatasheetRepository extends JpaRepository<Datasheet, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Datasheet>
```

I am doing this in my Controller:

```
Page<Datasheet> page = m_datasheetRepository.findAll( new PageRequest( pageNumber, pageSize, createSortForDatasheets() ) );
```

This is what I had with JPA:

```
private Sort createSortForDatasheets()
{
    // First sort on the component type name, then on the subtype name
    return new JpaSort( JpaSort.path( Datasheet_.componentSubtype ).dot( ComponentSubtype_.componentType ).dot( ComponentType_.name ) )
            .and( new JpaSort( JpaSort.path( Datasheet_.componentSubtype ).dot( ComponentSubtype_.name ) ) );
}
```

This is what I have changed it to for QueryDSL:

```
private Sort createSortForDatasheets()
{
    return new QSort( new OrderSpecifier<>( Order.ASC, QDatasheet.datasheet.componentSubtype.componentType.name,OrderSpecifier.NullHandling.NullsLast ) )
            .and( new OrderSpecifier<>( Order.ASC, QDatasheet.datasheet.componentSubtype.name, OrderSpecifier.NullHandling.NullsLast ) );
}
```

However, nothing seems to get sorted. I have enabled DEBUG logging and I see this:

```
Rendered criteria query -> select generatedAlias0 from Datasheet as generatedAlias0 order by generatedAlias0.name asc, generatedAlias0.name asc
```

If I change it to:

```
private Sort createSortForDatasheets()
{
    return new QSort(QDatasheet.datasheet.name.desc());
}
```

Then the sorting by the name of my "Datasheet" type in reverse order does work.

This is my "Datasheet" entity:

```
@Entity
public class Datasheet
{
// ------------------------------ FIELDS ------------------------------

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    private ComponentSubtype componentSubtype;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<DatasheetDocument> documents;
```

And this is "ComponentSubtype":

```
@Entity
public class ComponentSubtype
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id",insertable=false,updatable=false)
    private ComponentType componentType;
```

UPDATE:

If I change the `createSortForDatasheets` to this:

```
private Sort createSortForDatasheets()
{
    return new QSort( new OrderSpecifier<>( Order.ASC, QComponentType.componentType.id, OrderSpecifier.NullHandling.NullsLast ) );
}
```

Then, the logging shows:

```
Rendered criteria query -> select generatedAlias0 from Datasheet as generatedAlias0 order by generatedAlias0.id asc
```

Notice how the id of the "Datasheet" is used, and not the id of "ComponentType".

Comment: This looks like a bug in Spring Data. I will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Spring Data bug. I filed an issue for it https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-621

Comment: Bug confirmed. Was just fixed today in git: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/pull/111