# Ordering Nulls at the last of sorted list using createCriteria

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

i am facing a problem sorting a list that has null values !

What i need is that the null values appear at the last of the list when ordering ! as it seems now Nulls are on the top of my list when ordering it !

I couldn't use NullPrecedence as the hibernate version is 3.6.x

sample of my code !

```
SomeClass.createCriteria().list {
  eq('sth', sth)
  if (sort == 'someValue') {
    createAlias("nestedClass1", "nc1", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
    createAlias("nc1.nestedClass2", "nc2", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
    createAlias("nc2.nestedClass3", "nc3", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
    order("nc3.name", sortOrder)
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `nulls first/last`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683174/hibernate-order-by-with-nulls-last

Comment: How can i use it in my code ?

Comment: something along "$sortOrder nulls last"; but might depend on your actual DB

Comment: i tried this but the nulls now appear first all the time ! tried "$sortOrder nulls first" as well ! still the same !

Answer (score 2):

you can add new field in your domain class with mapping to formula that checks if it's null, and then sort by this extra field:

```
class SomeClass {
    String name
    boolean nameNotNull

    static mapping = {
        nameNotNull formula: 'name is not null'
    }
}



SomeClass.createCriteria().list() {
    order ('nameNotNull', 'desc')
    order ('name', 'asc')
}
```

Comment: actually the class name isn't nullable ! but i'm using this class as nested object (property )and this property (object ) could be null