# NullHandling.NULLS_LAST not working

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to add to a list management with null values
Results with null values must leave at the end.
Add the option to the Order class in two different ways in the SQL query but nothing appears.
I am using Oracle and if the consultation launched from a management database with null values results are listed at the end by default.

This is my code:

```
List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
orders.add(new Order(Direction.DESC, "points"));

//THIS
orders.add(new Order(Direction.DESC, "person.date", NullHandling.NULLS_LAST));
//OR THIS
orders.add(new Order(Direction.DESC, "person.date").nullsLast());
//NOT WORKING 

orders.add(new Order(Direction.DESC, "id"));
List<Foo> foos = fooRepository.findAll(new Sort(orders));
```

How I can specify that null results should go to the end?

Answer (score 16):

Maybe is a little late but you can check this out ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683174/hibernate-order-by-with-nulls-last)).

In our case, we solved it using hibernate property `hibernate.order_by.default_null_ordering` sugested by uwolfer; when we tried to use spring data function nulls last didn't work for us.

You can set this property in your Spring (Boot) `application.yml`:

```
spring:
    jpa:
        properties:
            hibernate.order_by.default_null_ordering: last
            # or for first: hibernate.order_by.default_null_ordering: first
```

Comment: This will affect the other api as well. what if we need solution for only one api

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem.

```
List<Sort.Order> orderList = new ArrayList<Sort.Order>();
    orderList.add(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC,"landArea",nullHandling.NULLS_LAST));

    Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, PAGE_SIZE, new Sort(orderList));
    Page<SearchSvcAttribsEntity> PropertySearchEntityList =
            searchSvcAttribsRepository.findAll(PropertySearchSvcAttribsSpecs.findByCriteria(propertySearchCriteria), pageable)
```

;

should generate sql: order by desc nulls last
but generates:
order by desc (chops off the nulls last)

I'm using this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency
```

Comment: same problem with hibernate 5.0.2

Comment: same problem with me. any solution found?

I am using this dependency

  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug of Spring Data JPA. [See here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/1280) .