# Nulls last in hibernate 3.6 GA and Spring 4

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data, hibernate-criteria

I am using PostgreSQL database with Hibernate and Spring Rest. 
I am getting sorted data in Hibernate Criteria from Postman but when data is sorted on descending order the NULL values come first, I believe this may be how PostgreSQL is sending data to Hibernate.
I know in Hibernate 4.2.x and 4.3.x there are ways to implement this using `Order` as shown below

```
Criteria criteria = ...;
criteria.addOrder( Order.desc( "name" ).nulls(NullPrecedence.LAST) );
```

But there is no similar implementation in 3.6 as I was getting compilation when I tried the same.
From [Hibernate order by with nulls last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683174/hibernate-order-by-with-nulls-last) I tried setting the Hibernate properties:

```
hibernate.order_by.default_null_ordering=last
```

It did not help me.

I am setting it as Hibernate configuration parameter, but it's not working.
I have to modify legacy code which is using Criteria so **how can I implement NULLs ordering while using Criteria in Hibernate 3.6**?

Comment: If someone could possibly tell me a workaround I have tried what I might.

Comment: even I am facing the same issue. Do let me know in case u find a workaround.

Comment: have u found any workaround ?

Comment: Nope I don't, have tried multiple website