# Any workaround for the openjpa to do ORDER BY NULLS LAST | FIRST query?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, openjpa

We are now using the spring-data-jpa(v1.10.2.RELEASE) and openjpa(v2.2.2) and have to do the ORDER BY query with NULLS LAST as code below.

```
Sort.Order order = new Sort.Order(Direction.DESC, "latestConnectTime", NullHandling.NULLS_LAST);

Sort sort = new Sort(order);

PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(1, 20, sort);
```

It looks like the EclipseLink and Hibernate have already supported this feature, the openjpa, however, doesn't?

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/1185 (formerly DATAJPA-825/925)
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/1626 (formerly DATAJPA-1302)
https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/issues/76
https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/issues/130

And the hibernate also does the workaround by the EmptyInterceptor or just configure the hibernate property `hibernate.order_by.default_null_ordering` as the link below.

[Hibernate order by with nulls last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683174/hibernate-order-by-with-nulls-last)

Is there any workaround for the openjpa to do the ORDER BY NULLS LAST query?