# Null Last is not working with spring data jpa

Tags: spring, spring-boot, pagination, spring-data-jpa

**NULL LAST** is not working with spring data JPA.

Here is the code that I am using.

Code of service layer:

```
Sort sort = new Sort(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "user_name").nullsLast());
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 10, sort);
userRepository.findAllUsers(pageable)
```

Code of repo layer:

```
@Query(value = "Select * from users", nativeQuery = true)
Page<User> findAllUsers(Pageable pageable);
```

Output expected/actual:

```
Expected: Null values should come at the last
Actual: Null values are coming at the top
```

Using

```
Spring Boot version: **2.1.6.RELEASE**
Database Postgres version: **42.2.5**
```

Can any buddy help me out here?

Comment: What database are you using? And can you please post the executed SQL?

Comment: I am using postgresSql and below is executed sql code in spring data jpa:  


`@Query(value = "Select * from users", nativeQuery = true)
Page<User> findAllUsers(Pageable pageable);`

Comment: What Simon is asking is not for the code you already posted. He's asking for the actual, complete SQL query generated and executed, at runtime, by Spring Data JPA.

Comment: @Simon Generated query by jpa:
 
    `Select
        * 
    from
        users 
    order by
        password desc limit ?`

Comment: The auto-generated query does not contain `nulls last`. I don't know why?

Comment: but in the example its new Sort(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "user_name").nullsLast()); How that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683174/hibernate-order-by-with-nulls-last

Answer (score 20):

I have searched many blogs, but you can't write this in repository methods. You can use the below config in application.properties. I'm using spring boot 2.1.9.RELEASE. Its working for me.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_by.default_null_ordering=last
```

Comment: Thanks @mohan.
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_by.default_null_ordering=last
This one perfectly worked for me

Comment: Works for me also :) Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I'm a little late to the show, but I ran into a similar problem and spent a LONG time finding a solution.

While `Sort.nullsFirst()` and `Sort.nullsLast()` apparently don't work when `nativeQuery = true`, `JpaSort.unsafe()` does work. Furthermore, `coalesce` works in `JpaSort.unsafe()`.

In my situation where I wanted null dates first, I used
`JpaSort.unsafe("COALESCE(date_of_birth, TO_DATE('1000-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))");` to treat null birthdates as dates that would almost always appear first when sorting ascending.

You may be able to do something similar depending on the column type you're trying to sort if you don't feel comfortable changing the default ordering properties across your application.