# Make NULLS FIRST when asc sorting from PostgreSQL. Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with sorting data from PostgreSQL.

I am sorting data from DB using `PagingAndSortingRepository`. The code is shown below:

```
List<Sort.Order> orders = new ArrayList();
orders.add(Sort.Order.asc(s.getField()));

Sort sort = Sort.by(orders);

Pageable pageSort = PageRequest.of(pageNumber,pageSize, sort);
List<Result> results = repository.findAll(pageSort);
```

As a result I have sorted data, but data with NULL values comes last, when I prefer it to come first.

I would like NULLS to go first when sorting in ascending order, and last when sorting in descending order.

But PostgreSQL by default puts NULLS at the end when sorting in ascending order and at the beginning when sorting in descending order.

I tried to use

```
new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, s.getField(), Sort.NullHandling.NULLS_FIRST)
```

but it seems like `NULLS_FIRST` property is ignored in generated query:

```
select generatedAlias0 
from Table as generatedAlias0 
order by generatedAlias0.targetField asc
```

As you can see there is no mention about NULL ORDERING.

Do you know other way how to solve my problem?

Please notice, that I am asking not about pg script, but about how can I solve problem through java code.

Comment: Can you bypass the ORM and send SQL directly to the server?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-order.html#:~:text=The%20NULLS%20FIRST%20and%20NULLS,order%2C%20and%20NULLS%20LAST%20otherwise.  but you already know about nulls first....  so maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57623565/null-last-is-not-working-with-spring-data-jpa  which says to use: `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_by.default_null_ordering=first` in the application.properties. or as a hack to assign null the earliest possible value with coalesce so... coalesce(orders,'0') so 0 is assigned to orders assuming it would be the earliest order when sorted...