# @NamedQuery in @OneToMany mapping

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have 2 entities `Parent` and `Child` and `@OneToMany` relationship between them.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT")
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Child.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PARENT_ID")
    private List<Child> children;

    // some other attributes and methods
}
```

```java
@Entity
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "myQuery" query = "here is some query with where and order by clauses")
@Table(name = "CHILD")
public class Child {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CHILD_ID")
    private Integer id;

    // some other attributes and methods
}
```

I would like to use `@NamedQuery` or `@NamedNativeQuery` for the mapping of children attribute.

Is there some way to call this named query in `OneToMany` mapping?

Comment: Hibernate has filters you can add to a mapping, and there are native customizations outside of JPA that might allow you to modify the query it'll use to fetch relationships, but IMO you are better off NOT doing what you are attempting. Once you do, you are forever tied to how Parents will see their children ,and it may not reflect what is actually in the database. That also makes handling changes more of a problem. Otherwise, if all you want is a particular sort/ordering on the list returned see the orderby annotation https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OrderBy.html

Comment: @Chris actually the whole issue is about the `ORDER BY` clause. There are not actually any conditions in the `WHERE` clause needed. All I need to achieve is to order children by a column named `ORDER_NUMBER`, which can be also null. At first I have used the `@OrderBy` annotation to achieve this and let hibernate to create the whole sql behind the scenes. The only issue is that our app could use different databases and therefore those different databases have different strategy to order nulls. I wanted to add `NULLS LAST` into the `@OrderBy` annotation, but it does not support that.

Comment: So actually the whole idea about using the `@NamedNativeQuery` was to be able to use `NULLS LAST` in order by and therefore I wouldn't be scared with the issue you mentioned above about not reflecting what really is in the database. The whole `WHERE` clause would be just mapping the connection between Parent and Child by PK = FK. A workaround that I found was to use `nvl2()` inside of `@OrderBy` and replacing the nulls with some big number, but I really don't want to use this workaround because it seems nasty to me.

Comment: Your solution would seem to have the same problem using the OrderBy does: it is not database agnostic. Hibernate and other providers do allow specifying NULLS LAST in JPQL (beyond the spec), but you might be better off overriding how Hibernate writes out the ASC/DESC. In eclipseLink, it would be a matter of overriding the FunctionOperator to use the same as what is used for the nullsLast/nullsFirst instead. Hibernate should have something similar, but the best I found is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683174/hibernate-order-by-with-nulls-last